# Citation on page 1 undefined

Tags: bibtex, citing

I've got a problem:

I want to cite a page, but in my document there comes this: Citation `Lehrer2000' on page 1 undefined

My LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{natdin}

\begin{document}
\citep{Lehrer2000}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliography{lit2}
\end{document}
```

My Bibtex:

```
@ONLINE{Lehrer2000,
    AUTHOR = "Lehrerinnenfortbildung",
    TITLE = "Projektkompetenz. Definition Methoden",
    HOWPUBLISHED = "https://lehrerfortbildung-bw.de/st_kompetenzen/weiteres/projekt/projektkompetenz/methoden/index.htm [11.10.2019]",
}
```

Comment: Did you run `bibtex`?

Comment: Yes and another citation worked before

Comment: What's the output from the `bibtex` run?

Answer (score 2):

The presence of an `_` (underscore) character in the URL throws off BibTeX and LaTeX. You should (a) change

```
HOWPUBLISHED = "https://lehrerfortbildung-bw.de/st_kompetenzen/weiteres/projekt/projektkompetenz/methoden/index.htm [11.10.2019]",
```

to

```
HOWPUBLISHED = "\url{https://lehrerfortbildung-bw.de/st_kompetenzen/weiteres/projekt/projektkompetenz/methoden/index.htm} [11.10.2019]",
```

and (b) load the `xurl` package in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{lit4.bib}
@ONLINE{Lehrer2000,
    AUTHOR = "Lehrerinnenfortbildung",
    year   = "(no year)",
    TITLE  = "Projektkompetenz. Definition Methoden",
    HOWPUBLISHED = "\url{https://lehrerfortbildung-bw.de/st_kompetenzen/weiteres/projekt/projektkompetenz/methoden/index.htm} [11.10.2019]",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[round,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\cite{Lehrer2000}
\bibliography{lit4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working now